# X and Y-axis swapped in Vision Framework Swift

Tags: ios, swift, vision

I'm using Vision Framework to detecting faces with iPhone's front camera. My code looks like

```
  func detect(_ cmSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(cmSampleBuffer) else {return}
    var requests: [VNRequest] = []
    
    let requestLandmarks = VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest { request, _ in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation],
        print(results)
      }
    }
    requests.append(requestLandmarks)
            
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: .leftMirrored)
    do {
      try handler.perform(requests)
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }
```

However, I noticed that when I move my face horizontally, the coordinates change vertically and vice versa. The image bellow can help to understand

[image]

If anyone can help me i'm going crazy about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, remove

```
let connectionVideo = videoDataOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)
connectionVideo?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
```

from my `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` solved the problem